# Moving files from one directory to another preserving subdirectories

Tags: bash, shell, directory, filesystems

I have directory with content (example)

```
/dir1/a/b/c/file1
/dir1/a/b/c/file2
/dir1/a/d/file3
/dir1/a/e/file4
/dir1/f/dir3/
/dir1/f/dir4/
```

...
I have list of files and directories, which can be removed - for example file1,file3 and dir3

I would like to move(move, not copy nor tar them - files are large and i need to do it in short time) them to another directory /dir2 (on the same filesystem), but - preserving subdirectories:

```
/dir1/a/b/c/file1 -> /dir2/a/b/c/file1
/dir1/a/d/file3 -> /dir2/a/d/file3
/dir1/f/dir3/ -> /dir2/f/dir3/
```

Is there any better way than for each file and directory(for directories skipping last part) create directory in dir2(using mkdir -p/install -d) and then moving it into?

Comment: Where and how do you have the files/directories that you want to move listed?

Comment: what about `mv /dir1/* /dir2/` ? you need to create dir2 first then.

Comment: i dont want to move everything from dir1 - only specific directories/files on different depth level.

Comment: one of simplest solutions is using rsync, with list of files in --include-from, and with --remove-source-files. But - it copy files, and then remove then - i need to avoid copying - for large files it take too much time.

Comment: Rename the directory, then remove unneeded files? Providing, that it is possible in your case.

Comment: use `find` then, adjust the `-wholename` tag and combine it with `-exec` to sth like `find ./dir1/ -wholename "./dir1/a/*" -or -wholename "./dir2/b/*" -exec mv {} ./dir2/ \;`

Answer (score 1):

> one of simplest solutions is using rsync, with list of files in
>   --include-from, and with --remove-source-files. But - it copy files, and then remove then - i need to avoid copying - for large files it
>   take too much time.

If you are comfortable with `rsync`, you can use it just to list the files and then process that list with this short shell script:

```
cd dir1
rsync --files-from list --list-only --no-implied-dirs . / |
while read mode size date time path
do
    dest=$dir2/`dirname $path`  # $dir2 must be an absolute path
    mkdirhier $dest
    mv $path $dest
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this code with example you mentioned above and it worked okay.. Please test it before you use it. In second line, you have to put all file names in a plain text file and provide it's path. My file contents are shown below

```
#!/bin/ksh
c_file="Path_to_the_file_containing_list_for_movement"
while IFS= read v_line
do
    v_fullfilepath=$(find $1 -name "$v_line")
    v_dirname=$(dirname $v_fullfilepath)
    v_target_path=${v_dirname/$1\//$2/}
    mkdir -p "$v_target_path"
    mv $v_fullfilepath $v_target_path
    #echo $v_line " "  $v_fullfilepath " " $v_dirname " " $v_target_path
done <"$c_file"
```

This was my file contents,

```
file1
file3
dir3
```

Comment: It will not work when there is a file with the same name in /dir1/a and /dir1/b ;) - there should be used -wholename instead of -name, and in file should be absolute paths. On the other hand - there will be problems with weird filenames (for example with $, spaces etc inside)
I've already something simmilar for that script, but - i'm looking for simpler and more error-proof solution.